# I am having trouble converting a linq list into a string list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. The first one is a list of strings that I then count the number of times a string repeats itself within the list. In the foreach loop I add convert those values and add them to my second list. However when I go to print out the items in the second list I get this "System.Linq.Grouping`2[System.String,System.String]" for every item in the list... I can not find a way to convert the linq values into string values.

```
        //LIST #1
        List<string> mlist = new List<string>(new string [] {"Line5","Line2", "Line3", "Line4", 
       "Line6", "Line5", "Line5", "Line5", "Line6", "Line6", "Line2" });

        //LIST #2
        List<string> newlist = new List<string>();
        var g = mlist.GroupBy(i => i);

        
        
        foreach (var grp in g)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
            newlist.Add(grp.ToString());
        }

        
        foreach(string line in newlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(line));
        }
```

Comment: Try `newList.Add(grp.Key)` instead of `newlist.Add(grp.ToString())`

Comment: What values do you expect to see in `newlist`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this, however you can't just print an `IGrouping<T>` with `Console.WriteLine()`. You will need to access its properties

```
foreach (var grp in groups)
   Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key} --- {grp.Count()}");
```

**Output**

```
Line5 --- 4
Line2 --- 2
Line3 --- 1
Line4 --- 1
Line6 --- 3
```

Another easy way, is to project to a `ValueTuple`, which has a special `ToString` *override*

```
var groups = items
   .GroupBy(i => i)
   .Select(x => (x.Key, Count : x.Count()));

foreach (var grp in groups)
   Console.WriteLine(grp);
```

**Output**

```
(Line5, 4)
(Line2, 2)
(Line3, 1)
(Line4, 1)
(Line6, 3)
```

Or customise

```
var groups = items
   .GroupBy(i => i)
   .Select(x => (x.Key, Count : x.Count()));

foreach (var grp in groups)
   Console.WriteLine(@$"My words = {grp.Key}, occurrence = {grp.Count}");
```

**Output**

```
My words = Line5, occurrence = 4
My words = Line2, occurrence = 2
My words = Line3, occurrence = 1
My words = Line4, occurrence = 1
My words = Line6, occurrence = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to convert it into a readable string, because you did this in the `Console.WriteLine` call above it.

```
    foreach (var grp in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
        newlist.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count()));
    }
```

Since this question has a linq tag, lets do it in one line:

```
List<string> newlist = g.Select(grp => $"{grp.Key} {grp.Count()}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this out

  List<string> mlist = new List<string>(new string [] {"Line5","Line2", "Line3", "Line4", 
                "Line6", "Line5", "Line5", "Line5", "Line6", "Line6", "Line2" });

            //LIST #2
            List<string> newlist = new List<string>();
            var g = mlist.GroupBy(i => i);

        
        
            foreach (var grp in g)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
                newlist.Add($"{grp.Key} {grp.Count()}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("New List");
            foreach(string line in newlist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(line));
            }
```

Use this link for confirmation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GhK6Tl